# css position error IE8/IE9

Tags: css, position, internet-explorer-9

Im developing a small web app, but i'm having problems with different browsers.

It seems ok on Chrome, Firefox,

but in IE9 (compatibility mode) the Div menu doesnt position the same way that the other browser,
also in IE9 (normal mode) it position ok the Div menu, but the div below the menu does not appear ok.

the site: http://tinyurl.com/3nmkxjs

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!
Joao

Answer (score 0):

Having problems with IE is normal and expected. It's an inept browser.

Remove all the spaces before the doctype to make sure that's not putting IE into quirks mode. I thought that problem was fixed in IE8, though.

Comment: i resolved putting a table with the images instead of positioning Divs.